# Is the following definition of continuity accurate?

Tags: continuity, definition

Is the following (rather wordy) definition of continuity accurate?

Let $f$ be a function with domain $A$, $ $ then $\forall x \in A$ $ $ and $ $ 
 for $c \in A$, $ $  $f$ is continuous at $c$;

if when $\delta>0$ is the length of the interval $[x, c]$, for $x<c$, $ $ or the length of the interval $[c, x]$, for $c<x$,
there exists $\varepsilon>0$, $ $ such that $\varepsilon$ is the length of the interval $[f(x), f(c)]$, $ $ if $f(x)<f(c)$, $  $  or the length of the interval $[f(c), f(x)]$, $  $ if $f(c)<f(x)$.

-

EDITED version (after the comments and answers below):

Let $f$ be a function with domain $A$, $ $ then $\forall x \in A$ $ $ and $ $ 
 for $c \in A$, $ $  $f$ is continuous at $c$;

if when $\delta>0$ is the length of the interval $[x, c]$, for $x<c$, $ $ or the length of the interval $[c, x]$, for $c<x$,
there exists $\varepsilon>0$, $ $ such that $\varepsilon$ is the length of the interval $[f(x), f(c)]$, $ $ if $f(x)<f(c)$, $  $  or the length of the interval $[f(c), f(x)]$, $  $ if $f(c)<f(x)$, $ $  **and this interval is a subset of $f(A)$**.

---

Just trying to rephrase this in my own words to make sure I understand the actual definition.

The key idea here is the intervals, so I could get rid of the $\varepsilon$ and the $\delta$, to simplify it a bit, but that would defeat the purpose of the "$\varepsilon$ - $\delta$"  definition, I suppose.

Comment: This is how I understand your proposal; the function is continuous  at $c$ if forall $x$ in the domain the existence of the interval $[x,c]$(or $[c,x]$) implies that $[f(x),f(c)]$(other the other way around) exists. But you did not gave restrictions at all. Say $f$ is $1$ everywhere and $0$ at $0$. You definition says that that there exist interval from $0$ to any $1$, hence it is continuous, could you explain a little more? Because I think I just misunderstood you

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.   In the example you gave  f is not continuous at 0, because  [f(0), f(x)] (or  [f(x), f(0)] ) is not an interval with a nonzero length **in the image set** of $f$.  (e.g. 0.5 is not in the image set of $f$)  Does this clear it up?  My mistake seems to be the fact that I did not specify that the interval  [f(c), f(x)] (or  [f(x), f(c)] )  must exist in the image set! (i.e. it must be a subset of the image)   Do you agree, or I'm still missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. See, the mathematical definition has an $\epsilon$ before a $\delta$, and your statement goes : "If, when $\delta$ is ... , there exists $\epsilon > 0$ ...".

The mathematical definition goes roughly like : "If, when $\epsilon > 0$ is ..., there exists $\delta > 0$ ...", so you have got the two mixed up, a highly common mistake.

If I were to write the definition of continuity for you, then I would do it as follows:

Given a function $f$, with domain $A$ and a point $c \in A$, $f$ is continuous at the point $c$, if: for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta > 0$, such that for every point $x$, if the distance between $x$ and $c$ is smaller than $\delta$, then the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.

Note the order of variables in this definition(forget $f,A,c$ : these are part of the definition, but they match up in the definition you and I provide and are correctly provided, so you may ignore these).

- First, comes $\epsilon > 0$. Usually, this step is phrased as "*given* $\epsilon > 0$". The word *given* is important, since here we don't get to *decide* $\epsilon$, but rather somebody(not influenced by us) gives us an $\epsilon > 0$ and (without protest) we must work with it.
- Then, comes the $\delta > 0$, which *possibly*(note : in some cases it may not) depends on $\epsilon$, and is *your decision to make*. That is, you may have to *decide* your $\delta$ based on the $\epsilon > 0$ that is given to you.
- How must you decide the $\delta$? This is given as follows : for every  $x$ which is in the domain, and whose distance from $c$ is less than $\delta$, we must have that the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ is less than $\epsilon$.

That is, if some point is $\delta$-close to $c$, then its image under $f$ is $\epsilon$-close to $f(c)$.

---

So let's correct your statement. The $\epsilon - \delta$ order must be restored, and the intervals must be made two-sided, since we are only saying above that $x$ is *close* to $c$, not to the left or right. An interval of the form $[c,x]$ is indicative of such an order, and is therefore a *problem* in the definition, one that must be avoided in any rephrasing.

> Given a function $f$ with domain $A$ and a point $c \in A$, $f$ is said to be continuous at $c$, if *given* $\epsilon > 0$, *we can find a* $\delta > 0$, such that for all $x$ in the domain satisfying $|x-c| < \delta$, $x$ will also satisfy $|f(x) -  f(c)| < \epsilon$.

Once again, I request you to observe the *order of the variables* in this definition. This is all you have got wrong,so good effort nevertheless.

Comment: Note : In case your visitor number(to my profile page) is divisible by $25$, please request for extended discussion or you can refer me to another unanswered question of yours, I will be at your disposal.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I missed your reply for some reason...  Thanks for the details.  You say, the only mistake was the order, but wasn't the edit I just made in my question also needed?

Comment: I believe I see what's going on now.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think now you have the hang of it. If not, the give it a little more time. The definition of continuity is very important, so much so, that the more time you take to understand it, the better you will understand it. You can come back  to this answer as and when you are confused on the definition. Also, you may attempt as many times to rephrase the above definition in words, and you can intimate me here so I can correct you.

Comment: Thanks!  Here's a somewhat different way of expressing this same idea.  Do you think it's accurate?  $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ $ " For any given epsilon, there exists a delta, such that the set $f([c-\delta, c+\delta])$ is contained in the interval $[f(c)-\varepsilon, f(c)+\varepsilon]$ ".

Comment: Brilliant. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong. Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}\chi_{\mathbb Q}\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ is discontinuous everywhere, but it would be continuous according to your definition (for each $\delta>0$, take $\varepsilon=2$).

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure, because $\varepsilon$ cannot be 2, since the **length** of the interval  [f(x), f(c)],  with your defined function, cannot be 2.  (in fact, it's always equal to 0 or 1  for all x in R, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @Stephen You're right. Take $\varepsilon=1$, then.

Comment: But any interval of length  $\varepsilon = 1$, cannot be a **subset of the image set** of the function as defined, and so w can't take epsilon=1  either (which seems to be the missing requirement in my suggestion).  Do you agree with my correction in the OP?

Comment: @Stephen I know that the image of the function has no intervals of length $1$. That doesn't change the fact that you are the one who mentioned intervals of the type $\bigl[f(x),f(c)\bigr]$, not me. And if $x=\sqrt2$ and $c=2$, then the length of $\bigl[\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x),\chi_{\mathbb Q}(c)\bigr]$ is $1$. It's not my fault.

Comment: I'm not blaming you at all.  It's my own omission, as I'm still trying to understand this definition - I just came across it in my text book (I had been using the sequence definition so far).  So, the idea is to rephrase it in my own words to make sure I understand it.  Do you agree with the edit I made in the OP?  Thanks!

Comment: @Stephen No, and I will not agree with any version in which the $\delta$ is mentioned before the $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

This is nice interpretation but *wrong*.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\text{ everywhere apart from $0$}\\\text{undefined at $0$}\end{cases}$$

Let's choose $c=1$ and $x=-1$, so we have the interval $[-1,1]$ but the interval $[f(-1),f(1)]$ have a point outside of the image, although the function is continuous at $1$.

The problem is that the initial part is $\delta$ and not $\varepsilon$.

Now consider the following: for any $\varepsilon>0$ exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $x$ is in domain and in $[c-\delta,c+\delta]$ then $f(x)$ is in the interval $[f(c)-\varepsilon,f(c)+\varepsilon]$.

This is different because you can see that $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$, maybe it is clearer like this.

In words it means: we say that $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$ if for any distance from $f(c)$ we take we there exists a distance from $c$ such that if we are within the distance from $c$ we are also within the distance from $f(c)$

Comment: Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks!